# Use two stored procedures in VB

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

I am writing a program that need's to use two stored procedures in same `sub`.

The one is a `GET` and the other is a `Update` What they do is the one get's the URL's of images and what I want to do is use the Update to use 2 if the image retrieval was successful and 3 if error. This program should get images from a url e.g :`www.company.com/234567.jpg` and save them locally with the name as what ever is after the `/`

The table the stored procedures use have a column for idestination where I want to use the 2 or 3

So my question is: how do I use the two stored procedures and the one needs to use the other one? The one needs to get images and other have to see if its downloaded and then update.

My VB:

```vb
Dim cmdGet As New SqlCommand("ETSP_GET_PHOTO_URLS")
Dim cmdUpdate As New SqlCommand("ETSP_UPDATE_PHOTO_URLS")

Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings(("ConnectionString")))
cmdGet.Connection = conn
cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmdGet.ExecuteNonQuery()

cmdGet.Parameters("@count").Value = 10

Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdGet)

Dim ds As DataSet
adapter.Fill(ds)

Dim client As New WebClient
Dim pofneus As String

For Each DR As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    pofneus = GetFileNameFromURL(CStr(DR(1)))
    client.DownloadFile(CStr(DR(1)), "c:\images\" & pofneus)
    client.Dispose()
Next

loopthroughfiles(pofneus)
conn.Close()
```

I used VB but I don't mind C# help

Comment: Is there an actual question? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Code review: I would personally do this in 3 functions. One that calls get from the database. An other that checkes the file. And a third that update the database.

Comment: @ckuhn203: HOW DO I USE TWO STROED PROCS AND THE ONE NEEDS TO USE THE OTHER ONE. The one gets and then the other one must see if it actually got it.

Comment: @the_lotus true! I will do that as soon as i get the stored proc's going, thanx though for suggestion.

Comment: @user3458266 I agree with [the_lotus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253854/use-two-stored-procedures-in-vb#comment35583493_23253854), your logic should be seperated, you dont want messy code

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be accomplished by using a `try catch` block around the download part as follows:

```
For Each DR As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    pofneus = GetFileNameFromURL(CStr(DR(1)))
    Try
        client.DownloadFile(CStr(DR(1)), "c:\images\"" & pofneus)
        ' Call update procedure with 2
    Catch e as Exception
        ' Call update procedure with 3
    Finally
        client.Dispose()
    End Try
Next
```